# Finding country with highest percentage of workers working above 50K

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

Need to calculate **What country has the highest percentage of people that earn >50K?**
Here is the preview of dataset used
Expected Answer is Iran with 41.9%
[1994 census dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcssK.jpg)
**My approach**

```
country = df[df['income']==">50K"][['sex','native.country']] top = country.describe()                                                         top.loc['top','native.country']
```

Comment: My code so far   @Priyal                                                                                                `country = df[df['income']==">50K"][['sex','native.country']]
top = country.describe()                                                         top.loc['top','native.country']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p = (df[df['salary'] =='>50K']['native-country'].value_counts()
 /df['native-country'].value_counts()*100).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Then, get first value with `p.iloc[0]`

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you stored your dataset into a variable named new.

```
#converting your sex column into numerical values to calculate the population
gender={'male':1,'female':2}
new.sex=[gender[item] for item in new.sex]

#calculating your desired result

data=new.loc[new.income>50K,['sex','native.country']]
result=data.groupby('native.country')['sex'].sum()
print(result)
```

This will give you the country's name with the  highest population of people getting over 50k income.

Then, if you still want to find the  percentage  of population, you can easily do it by using:

```
total=data['sex'].sum()
list1=[]
for i in result:
    list1.append(i/total*100)
print(list1)
```

Hope, you find some help from my answer.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: My approach  `country = df[df['income']==">50K"][['sex','native.country']]
top = country.describe()  top.loc['top','native.country']`

Comment: appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! And yes, your approach is a good one.